# How can I swap specific column values in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe this is the sample part of the Dataframe.
Want to swap the Muscat and Shanghai values.

```
 df =
 City   Score

 Istanbul   6.0749
 2.23607    Muscat
 Prague     4.38576
 1.85958    Shanghai
 Istanbul   6.0749
 Singapore  5.17054
```

Output:

```
 df = 
 City   Score

 Istanbul   6.0749
 Muscat     2.23607     
 Prague     4.38576
 Shanghai   1.85958     
 Istanbul   6.0749
 Singapore  5.17054
```

I am  confused that how can I apply the condition after iterating through the dataframe, also is there any other alternative?

Comment: It might serve you better to look upstream and see why your data is coming in like this. As your dataset gets larger, changing the values becomes a more cumbersome task irrespective of performing it manually or with a function

Comment: I agree @aydow. Perhaps you have only an issue with some duplicate Separators or sth. However, it's always a good idea to prove that your data is OK, otherwise you risk to loose data in the attempt to heal it not knowing what causes which artifacts.

Comment: Point noted.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) for boolean mask and then swap by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['City'], errors='coerce').notna()
#oldier versions of pandas
#m = pd.to_numeric(df['City'], errors='coerce').notnull()
df.loc[m,['City','Score']] = df.loc[m,['Score','City']].values

print (df)
        City    Score
0   Istanbul   6.0749
1     Muscat  2.23607
2     Prague  4.38576
3   Shanghai  1.85958
4   Istanbul   6.0749
5  Singapore  5.17054
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
In [39]: mask = pd.to_numeric(df.Score, errors='coerce').isna()

In [40]: s = df.Score.copy()

In [41]: df.Score[mask] = df.City

In [42]: df.City[mask] = s

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
        City    Score
0   Istanbul   6.0749
1     Muscat  2.23607
2     Prague  4.38576
3   Shanghai  1.85958
4   Istanbul   6.0749
5  Singapore  5.17054
```